# One-liner possible?

Tags: python

I know that in Python this is possible:

```
'\n'.join(alist)
```

Assuming the 'alist' is a list of urls, can I output an HTML string which will produce a list of href tags, something like this

```
'<a href="'.join(alist)
```

I know the above is wrong, but I was wondering if there was a smarter way to do this. I have done the following with works:

```
for u in adict[alist]:
    fileHandle.write('<a href="' + u + '">' + u + '</a><br>')
```

Basically, is there a way of somehow replacing the above for loop with a join statement? A one-liner perhaps?

Comment: This is a horrible way to output HTML. For instance, it breaks as soon as `u` contains double quotes or ampersands or angle brackets. Use a templating system, or at least add some basic validation/escaping for these obvious problems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for a [generator expression](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions):

```
''.join('<a href="' + u + '">' + u + '</a><br/>' for u in adict[alist])
```

If you don't want a `<br/>` after the last item, move the `<br/>` into the string to join with.

Also, I'm assuming here `adict[alist]` contains HTML code. If it contains text, you must wrap `u` with [`html.escape()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/html.html) (replacing `<` with `&lt;` and `"` with `&quot;`). Otherwise, you're introducing a [Cross-Site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability (and rendering bugs).

Comment: The `<br />` should most likely be the string to join with

Comment: @phantOm This expression evaluates to a string, not a generator. The whole code looks like `fileHandle.write(''.join(...))`, left that out for clarity.

Comment: Heh... you are quick, I deleted my comments just seconds after posting it because it dawned on me what you meant :)

Comment: @phant0m Please avoid deleting comments. You may not be the only one confused by me leaving `fileHandle` out of the answer, and comments are a great way to discuss these finer points ;)

Comment: I wasn't really confused because fileHandle wasn't there, I just read `generator expression` and thought: "generator into `write()`? If I had waited just a second, I'd have noticed. As for deleting: Yes, that makes sense, wouldn't have done it if your reply had already been there - and I considered my comment to be the product of haste.

Answer (score 1):

Yes

```
fileHandler.write('<br/>\n'.join('<a href="%(url)s">%(url)s</a>' % {'url':u} for u in adict[alist])
```

EDITED: modified to use write method and join results using newline and '
' tag

Comment: Either `writelines` or `'\n'.join(..)` Using both will result in a newline after every character.

Comment: But i have runned this code several times locally and it produce me correct results.So what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, my mistake. `writelines` does **not** add newlines. However, using it is still superfluous and may introduce additional overhead. Also, it obfuscates what you're doing; the reinterpretation of a string as a sequence is far from obvious. Why do you prefer `writelines` over simply `write`?

Comment: I simply played around with write and writelines in order to find one line solution, however you are right and it using is superfluous here

Answer (score 1):

How about the following?

```
['<a href="{0}">{0}</a><br>'.format(u) for u in alist]
```

Update:

```
fileHandler.write('<br />\n'.join('<a href="{0}">{0}</a>'.format(u) for u in alist)
```

Comment: +1 for using new style string formatting.  You may want to add a `join` like in phihag's answer.